# How to set a:before css style from code behind aspx.cs page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a property in my aspx.cs page which contains the path of an image. I need to set this path as a background-image on a:before in css like this:

My property name in aspx.cs page is: FirstLinkIcon

now in .aspx page i am trying:

```
<style>
    .m-quick-links ul li a:before {
        background-image: url('<%=FirstLinkIcon%>');
        background-position: 0 -4164px;
    }
</style>
```

But it is throwing error in rendering page due to <%= %> use in css.

I also tried to set this style from code behind like this:

```
firstLinkUrl.Style.Add("background-image", FirstLinkIcon);
```

but it sets the background-image on anchor tag not for a:before

Please suggest how can i set the a:before style from code behind? or if it can't be done from code behind then how can i access the code behind property in css on aspx page as explained above?

I have searched about it but did not get any help so posting as a question.

Comment: did you have a master page or just a simple aspx page?

Comment: you said `But it is throwing error in rendering page due to <%= %> use in css`, i tested it and it works without problem. if you explain more about your scenario, i can help you how to do it more simpler than your answer about using `LiteralControl`

Comment: I have a Master page also.. but i need this style on a specific ascx page only. I am using Kentico CMS as well, in that i have a web part for my ascx page so when i am using <%= %> inside style tag on my ascx page then my web part is not loading and throwing syntax error due to <%= => keywords. @S.Serp

Comment: If you have any simple solution better than LiteralControl, please suggest i will try that as well. Thanks @S.Serp

Comment: where did you defined the `style` tag? inside that `usercontrol` or master page or aspx..? i tested `<%=..%>` in master page and also in simple aspx pages (which doesn't use any master) and it works.

Comment: in user control @S.Serp

Comment: did you try doing this ? firstLinkUrl.Style.Add(":before", FirstLinkIcon); ??

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya i need to assign the value of FirstLinkIcon to background-image css style and in your example you have not written background-image anywhere so it will not work.

Comment: @AnkitSahrawat the code which shared was sample for setting ":before" in the style of the link button. That one line alone will not work for sure. You already have the code of adding rest of the style attributes. You just need to arrange you code around the line which I shared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching on it finally i found a solution to my problem. For this i have created an object for LiteralControl, then created a style tag as a string using string builder by appending my property in it, now i have initialized LiteralControl's Text property to above style tag string and finally added the LiteralControl to page header.

It is rendering the generated style tag with property values in my page header and rendered style is applied on my page. Following is the code i used in code behind:

```
System.Web.UI.LiteralControl ltr = new System.Web.UI.LiteralControl();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("<style type=\"text/css\" rel=\"stylesheet\"> .m-quick-links ul li a:before { background-image: url(");
sb.Append(FirstLinkIcon); //here i am appending property value in css style
sb.Append(") !important; } </style>");
ltr.Text = sb.ToString();
this.Page.Header.Controls.Add(ltr);
```

Following is rendered style tag on my page header from this:

```
<style type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"> .m-quick-links ul li a:before { background-image: url(http://localhost:8082/assets/img/sprites/global-se8a7877705.png) !important; } </style>
```

Comment: you can also use directly `HtmlGenericControl style = new HtmlGenericControl("style");` instead of `LiteralControl`

Answer (score 0):

Unless there's something I've forgotten about ASP.NET, it's not possible to modify *anything* about a pseudo-element at run-time without changing a `<style>` element directly. I would recommend containing whatever data or logic you need within a non-pseudo element instead.

Answer (score 0):

I tested simple using of `<%=...%>` inside `style` and ensure it works.

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="UserControl1.ascx.cs" Inherits="TestWebForm1.UserControl1" %>
<style>
  .class1:before { content:'<%=getContent()%>'; color: green; }
</style>

<div class="class1" style=" padding:10px; border:1px solid silver; width:300px;">
  <span>This is UserControl1:</span><br />

  <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="utxt1" width="100px"></asp:TextBox>
  <asp:Button runat="server" ID="ubtn1" Text="+" OnClick="ubtn1_Click" />

</div>
```

and its code behind:

```
public partial class UserControl1 : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{

    public string getContent()
    {
        return DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();
    }
}
```

Note that its not good to embed style tags this way within your `usercontrol` as they will be rendered inside the `body` where you use them (not in `<head>` section).

Please say whats wrong with this in your situation?

Comment: Okay.. Thanks for your response if it is working at your end then i think in my application something is happening due to Kentico CMS as it is not working for me. I have a web part in kentico for every user control (.ascx page) of my application so when i use <%= %> this inside style tag my web part does not renders and throw error of invalid charactor <%=